# How to convert this awk command to PowerShell native?

Tags: powershell, awk, powershell-7.3

The original code was this:

```
curl -sL https://ftp.apnic.net/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-latest | \
grep "apnic|JP|ipv4" | \
awk -F '|' '{ printf("%s/%d\n", $4, 32-log($5)/log(2)) }' | \
tee JP_IPv4.txt
```

I wanted to convert it to PowerShell, this is how far I got:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://ftp.apnic.net/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-latest" |     
Select-String -Pattern "afrinic\|ZA\|ipv6" -ca | Select-Object -exp line |
```

I need to figure out how to convert the last part that uses `awk` command to PowerShell.

I use PowerShell 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `awk` script appears to calculate the subnet prefix length from the network size.

You can replace the awk `log(...)` function call with `[Math]::Log(...)` in PowerShell to perform the exact same calculation:

```
# this takes care of the `curl` part
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://ftp.apnic.net/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-latest" -OutFile delegated_networks.txt

# this takes care of the `grep` part
Get-Content delegated_networks.txt |Where-Object {$_ -like 'apnic|JP|ipv4|*'} 

# this emulates the `awk | tee` part
$data|ForEach-Object {
  # -F '|'
  $cells = $_.Split('|')
  # '{ printf("%s/%d\n", $4, 32-log($5)/log(2)) }'
  '{0}/{1}' -f $cells[3],(32 - [Math]::Log($cells[4])/[Math]::Log(2))
} |Tee-Object -FilePath JP_ipv4.txt
```

As @mklement0 kindly points out, you can also combine the log-conversion operation into a single call in PowerShell:

```
PS ~>[Math]::Log(4096)/[Math]::Log(2)
12
PS ~>[Math]::Log(4096, 2)
12
```

Comment: I'm having problem getting the first line to work. the servers I listed are too slow so I downloaded the files to a text file, when I use `Get-Content .\file.txt` I can see the exact same thing from the online website. when I run this, I get nothing. `Get-Content .\apnic.txt |ForEach-Object { $_.Content -split '\r?\n' } |Where-Object {$_ -like 'apnic|JP|asn|*'} `

Comment: @Jameschad I've updated the answer to take your download-to-file-first approach into account

Comment: Thank you, 98% of the results are good but some of them are like `196.10.130.0/21.192645077942394` or `196.10.150.0/18.356143810225277`, is it possible to fix that? it happens more often when I get IPv6.\

Comment: @Jameschad Try with `[Math]::Log($cells[4], 2)` instead of `[Math]::Log($cells[4])/[Math]::Log(2)`

Comment: didn't help https://imgur.com/a/OWUnoOS

Comment: Nevermind, I used `[Math]::Log(4096, 2)` and it fixed everything, thank you both! it works for any continent now and IPv4/IPv6. I just used `afrinic` as an example because their list is much smaller and faster.

Comment: @Jameschad Those are IPv6 addresses, not IPv4. Please share the actual URL you're using, I can't see any `afrinic|ZA|ipv6` entries in the list from apnic